# How to access DB/_local_docs on Cloudant without getting error "server_admin access is required for this request""

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I want to retrieve the list of local documents an my Cloudant Bluemix CouchDB.

Under CouchDB 2 i can `GET /db/_local_docs` to get a listing similar to _all_docs.

Unfortunately Cloudant returns following error when i call the endpoint:

```
{"error":"forbidden","reason":"server_admin access is required for this request"}
```

I tried to access the endpoint while logged in as account owner into the Cloudant Dashboard as well as authenticated with an API key.

I event tried to add an API key with the role server admin but without success

How can i access a list of local docs in Cloudant?

Comment: The /db/_all_docs endpoint works for me.

Comment: @EllaBlackledge /db/_all_docs is a different endpoint. It shows the synced docs. /db/_local_docs is supposed to show all docs that stay on the server and are not to be replicated.

Answer (score 2):

I turned this into an issue. See here https://github.com/ibm-cloud-docs/Cloudant/issues. This should allow tracking its progress.

In the documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-comparison-of-ibm-cloudant-and-couchdb-api-endpoints it shows that in CouchDB 1.6 only individual local documents can be accessed, and Couch DB 2.0 introduces the /db/_local_docs endpoint to list all local documents.

If you click on the Cloudant icon in that table, the documentation for /db/_local is missing. It appears that that functionality should be in Cloudant, but something is amiss.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I posted the OP's question on GitHub to be addressed by the Cloudant developers team, so my answer is not an answer but description of my attempt to resolve the problem. I don't have enough reputation to make it a comment. Please change to to a comment if you can. Thanks!

Comment: I could perceive this as an honest and helpful part of the answering process. Just rephrase a little. Maybe more like "I turned this into an issue. See here ... link. This should allow tracking its progress." The way you start this reads a little (in my opinion) too much like "Me too." If you get the "Helpful participation" feeling more prominent than the (misunderstood) "Me too." I am open to even upvote this.

Comment: @Yunnosch1, I made changes as you had suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am now convinced that this is a helpful participation. Admittedly I am quite out of my waters on technical level here, but I stand with my impression that the author posts info on helpful work for this topic.